# align*-environment aligns parts of equation to the right with multiple ampersands

Tags: equations, align

This following example aligns the last part of the equation to the right and I don't know why.
What I would expected to see instead is that the last parts of both lines start directly to the right of `...lcz(S_2))`.
How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    t_{1_\text{max}}&= \Delta t_1\cdot(T_1-\text{lzc}(S_1)) &= 16\cdot(15-\text{lzc}(S_1))\\
    t_{2_\text{max}}&= t_{1_\text{max}}+\Delta t_2\cdot(T_2-\text{lzc}(S_2)) &=   t_{1_\text{max}}+1\cdot(15-\text{lzc}(S_2)) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment `align` aligns equation systems. After the first system the next `&` goes to the left part of the second system. Therefore you need *two* ampersands. However `align` also sets space between the systems, that looks odd in this case, therefore the example uses `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    t_{1_\text{max}}&= \Delta t_1\cdot(T_1-\text{lzc}(S_1)) &&=
16\cdot(15-\text{lzc}(S_1))\\
    t_{2_\text{max}}&= t_{1_\text{max}}+\Delta t_2\cdot(T_2-\text{lzc}(S_2))
&&=   t_{1_\text{max}}+1\cdot(15-\text{lzc}(S_2))
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If `lzc` is a function like `sin` or `cos`, then `\lzc` can be defined to simplify the input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lzc}{lzc}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    t_{1_\text{max}}&= \Delta t_1\cdot(T_1-\lzc(S_1)) &&=  
16\cdot(15-\lzc(S_1))\\
    t_{2_\text{max}}&= t_{1_\text{max}}+\Delta t_2\cdot(T_2-\lzc(S_2))
&&=   t_{1_\text{max}}+1\cdot(15-lzc(S_2))
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```